# How do I open the Assembly Browser in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, monodevelop

I started learning c# recently.

I can open 'Assembly Browser' in 'MonoDevelop' by double clicking 'filename.dll'.

I cannot open 'Assembly Browser' in 'Visual Studio Code'.

Comment: In visual studio proper the object explorer is opened by the key combo `ctrl-w` , `j` Though I don't know if visual studio code has this, and I don't have it installed to try - what do you see? I also see around the web, people say this key combo as `ctrl-w ctrl-j` or `ctrl alt j` or `f12` or right click on a symbol and choose View In Object Browser - any of these perhaps?

Comment: @CaiusJard sorry, it doesn't work.... ; ^ ;

Answer (score 2):

Afaik there is (yet) no decompiler plugin for VS Code, that produces c#-/vb-code. You might use a standalone decompiler like [JetBrain's dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) (free) instead. If IL-code is what you need, you might have a look into [ILSpy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=icsharpcode.ilspy-vscode).